How to view and watch an image with Laravel Livewire
I am trying to recreate a reusable blade component that will allow me to view and upload images for all my forms. The value in the livewire component could be a string of a previously uploaded image or a newly uploaded image.
What I need it the component to show me what image I have already set and the image Im am changing it to.
I have my livewire component that has a form with an image variable
class CreateStall extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;
    public editStallForm $form;

    public function render()
    {
        return <<<'HTML'
        <div> 
           <x-inputs.image wire:model="form.image" />
        </div>
        HTML;
    }
}


I then have my image blade component that is responsable for showing the current image and the new image
<label >
    <input wire:model="{{ $attributes->wire('model')->value() }}" type="file" class="hidden" accept=".svg,.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif" />

    @if ($image)
        @if (is_string($image))
            <img src="{{ Storage::url($image) }}" class="absolute inset-0 aspect-auto w-full lg:max-h-64 lg:w-auto">
        @elseif ($image instanceof \Livewire\TemporaryUploadedFile)
            <img src="{{ $image->temporaryUrl() }}" class="absolute inset-0 aspect-auto w-full lg:max-h-64 lg:w-auto">
        @endif
    @endif
</label>

I have tried multiple ways of getting the image to the component... The most success ive had is with the x-data="image: @entange($attributes->wire('model')" but i can seem to find a way to allow it to update with the value changes

You're creating a reusable image upload component with Livewire. You want to display the current image and the newly uploaded image.
To achieve this, you'll need to:

Pass the current image URL to the component.

Update the component when a new image is uploaded.
Here's an updated version of your code:
CreateStall.php (Livewire Component)
class CreateStall extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;
    public $image; // Add a public property for the image
    public editStallForm $form;

    public function render()
    {
        return <<<'HTML'
        <div> 
           <x-inputs.image wire:model="image" :currentImage="$image" />
        </div>
        HTML;
    }

    public function updatedImage()
    {
        // Update the image property when a new image is uploaded
        $this->form->image = $this->image;
    }
}

image.blade.php (Component)
@props(['currentImage'])

<label>
    <input 
        wire:model="{{ $attributes->wire('model')->value() }}" 
        type="file" 
        class="hidden" 
        accept=".svg,.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif"
        x-data="imageData(@entangle($attributes->wire('model')->value()), '{{ $currentImage }}')"
        x-init="updateImageDisplay()"
        x-on:change="updateImageDisplay"
    />

    <div x-show="image">
        @if ($currentImage)
            <img :src="$currentImage" class="absolute inset-0 aspect-auto w-full lg:max-h-64 lg:w-auto">
        @elseif (image instanceof \Livewire\TemporaryUploadedFile)
            <img :src="image.temporaryUrl()" class="absolute inset-0 aspect-auto w-full lg:max-h-64 lg:w-auto">
        @endif
    </div>

    <script>
        function imageData(image, currentImage) {
            return {
                image,
                currentImage,
                updateImageDisplay() {
                    if (this.image instanceof \Livewire\TemporaryUploadedFile) {
                        this.currentImage = this.image.temporaryUrl();
                    } else if (this.image) {
                        this.currentImage = '{{ Storage::url('') }}' + this.image;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</label>

Explanation

We added a currentImage prop to the image component to display the initial image.

In the CreateStall component, we updated the image property when a new image is uploaded using the updatedImage method.

We use Alpine.js to manage the image display in the image component. We create an imageData function that takes the image and currentImage as arguments.

We used x-data to initialize the component with the imageData function.

We used x-on:change to update the image display when a new image is uploaded.

We used x-show to display the image conditionally.
This should solve the issue of updating the image display when a new image is uploaded.


Update:
The issue is due to the execution order in Alpine.js.
The x-data directive is executed after the template has been rendered, which means the image is undefined when the template is first rendered.
To fix this, you can use a slight modification to your code:
@props(['currentImage'])

<label 
    x-data="imageData({{ $currentImage }})"
    x-init="updateImageDisplay"
    x-on:change="updateImageDisplay"
>
    <input 
        wire:model="{{ $attributes->wire('model')->value() }}" 
        type="file" 
        class="hidden" 
        accept=".svg,.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif"
        x-ref="fileInput"
    />

    <div x-show="image">
        <img :src="image" class="absolute inset-0 aspect-auto w-full lg:max-h-64 lg:w-auto">
    </div>

    <script>
        function imageData(currentImage) {
            return {
                image: currentImage,
                updateImageDisplay() {
                    const fileInput = this.$refs.fileInput;
                    if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
                        const file = fileInput.files[0];
                        this.image = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    } else {
                        this.image = this.image || '{{ Storage::url('') }}' + currentImage;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</label>


This looks great, but I get an error that image is undefined on this line
@elseif (image instanceof \Livewire\TemporaryUploadedFile) on image.blade.php
Looks like the imageData function is not running before image is used

Thanks for the updated answer. This seems to be partually working with adding a new image although it seems to quickly disappear. I notice that when adding a new image it adds a src so the elements looks like <img :src="image" src="blob:http..."/>. Im not sure that this is intended or not but the bigger issue I see is that x-data does not seem to be calling imageData. HTML = x-data="imageData(public/events/...jpg)" I have tried to just @json for $currentImage but with no avail

The issues you're experiencing are due to:
Alpine.js rendering the :src attribute as src and then Livewire updating the image with a temporary URL, resulting in duplicate src attributes.
x-data not calling imageData function.
To resolve these issues:

Duplicate src attribute
Use x-bind:src instead of :src to bind the src attribute:
PHP
<img x-bind:src="image" class="absolute inset-0 aspect-auto w-full lg:max-h-64 lg:w_auto">

x-data not calling imageData function
You're passing a string to x-data, but it expects a JavaScript object or function.
Try changing x-data to:
PHP
x-data="{ imageData: imageData(@json($currentImage)) }"


Or, for better readability:
PHP
x-init="imageData(@json($currentImage))"
x-data="{ image: null, updateImageDisplay() { /* ... */ } }"`

Then, define the imageData function inside the x-data object:
PHP
<script>
function imageData(currentImage) {
    return {
        image: currentImage,
        updateImageDisplay() {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

However, I recommend simplifying your code. You don't need the imageData function. Instead, initialize the image directly:
PHP
x-data="{ image: @json($currentImage) }"

x-init="updateImageDisplay"
x-on:change="updateImageDisplay"
And update the updateImageDisplay function accordingly.
Full updated code
PHP
@props(['currentImage'])

<label 
x-data="{ image: @json($currentImage) }"
x-init="updateImageDisplay"
x-on:change="updateImageDisplay"
>
<input 
    wire:model="{{ $attributes->wire('model')->value() }}" 
    type="file" 
    class="hidden" 
    accept=".svg,.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif"
    x-ref="fileInput"
/>

<div x-show="image">
    <img x-bind:src="image" class="absolute inset-0 aspect-auto w-full lg:max-h-64 lg:w-auto">
</div>

<script>
    function updateImageDisplay() {
        const fileInput = this.$refs.fileInput;
        if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
            const file = fileInput.files[0];
            this.image = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        } else {
            this.image = this.image || '{{ Storage::url('') }}' + @json($currentImage);
        }
    }
</script>

